# Use xlim(,) and scale_x_reverse() together in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use xlim and scale_x_reverse together in a plot, e.g.:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg), . ~ cyl) + geom_point()
p + geom_line() +
  xlim(2, 5) +
  scale_x_reverse()
```

Both commands work independently, but not together.Instead I get:

```
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
```

Is there a way to get work at the same time?

Thanks,

Mace

Comment: Why not just use `+ xlim(5, 2)`? I do wonder if it's a warning or an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p + geom_line() +
  scale_x_reverse(limits = c(5, 2)) 
#Warning messages:
#1: Removed 7 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
#2: Removed 7 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image: first resulting plot]

```
p + geom_line() +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(5, 2))
```

[image: second resulting plot]

Answer (score 0):

Works with + xlim(5, 2) as suggested by BondedDust.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg), . ~ cyl) + geom_point()
p + geom_line() +
  xlim(5, 2)
```